# Disable Temporal History Retention in Visual Studio SQL Server 2017 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

Is there any way to set the database option for Temporal History Retention to off in a Visual Studio SQL Server 2017 Database project?

When I generate a script from my publish profile it adds the code below and I'm unable to find a way to prevent it.

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    SET TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION ON 
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

I don't want to prevent it from setting all db options as I do use others.   I only want to set this one to OFF so the script doesn't produce the output above.

- Visual Studio Version - Professional 2019 (16.4.5)
- SQL Server Data Tools - 16.0.62002.03150
- SQL Server Version - 2017 (14.0.3223.3)

I feel like i'm just missing a tick box somewhere?!?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Afraid not.  We had to add a step to our build process to to remove it from the script before running it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter /p:"ScriptDatabaseOptions=false"

Comment: Thanks for the response however that removes ALL databases level properties which would remove other functionality that we need.

Comment: Agreed, I don't want all options turned off, just that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the Sql Server Database Tools.

There is a MSBuid property `TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled` that is passed to the `SlqBuildTask` so I tried adding the `TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled` property to the SQL Server Database Project's sqlproj file:

```
<TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>Off</TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>
```

Unfortunately, I found that when I did this I got a build error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(507,5): Error:  MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.SetFieldInModelOptionsObject(KeyValuePair`2 propItem, SqlModelOptions modelOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.InitializeDatabaseOptions(String propertyThatChanged)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.Set(String propertyName, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.SetDatabaseModelOptionsProperties(SqlTaskHost host, IDictionary`2 properties)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.ValidateHost(SqlTaskHost& host, ErrorManager& errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.LoadImpl(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.Load(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteLoadTaskHostStep()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1 step)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

The build error goes away when the Target Platform is set to **Microsoft Azure SQL Database**. Any other Target Platform setting seems to cause problems.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent `TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION` from being set `ON` at lower Target Platform versions if the target database has the `TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION` set to `OFF`.

Comment: It should be `False`, not `Off`: `<TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>False</TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>`

Comment: @MattJeanes your answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `.sqlproj` file and add either `True` or `False` for the `TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled` param.

i.e.
`<TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>True</TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled>`

Edit: it seems to be a bug when importing a database/dacpac the option is set to On/Off depending on whether or not you choose to import database settings.